# KeyError: 'releases' when trying to follow the python gitlab API examples

Tags: gitlab-api, python-gitlab

I'm attempting to following the API example [here](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/releases.html), but it fails because apparently there is no `ProjectReleaseManager` on my project.

```
>>> gl.api_version
'4'
>>> gl_project = gl.projects.get("atlas/athena")
>>> gl_project.issues.list()
[]
>>> release = gl_project.releases.list()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/gitlab/1.4.0-python2.7-x86_64-slc6-gcc62/python_gitlab-1.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitlab/base.py", line 582, in __getattr__
    return self.__dict__['_updated_attrs'][name]
KeyError: 'releases'
```

(It's fine that issues returns an empty list - we have them turned off in our project, but I can successfully retrieve merge requests without problem)

Does anyone know why I do not have `releases`? Is there something I can do about it? (I'd like to be able to create a release from a script)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the logs, you're running an extremely old version of python-gitlab (1.4.0), likely installed via your OS package manager.

You'll need to install a later version (support for the releases API was added in 1.9.0), ideally in a virtual environment to keep it isolated. For example, assuming you have python3 installed, you can run this to install the latest version with a virtual environment in your current directory:

```
python3 -m venv .venv
. .venv/bin/activate
pip install python-gitlab
```

Note that you'll need to activate the virtual environment when running your scripts - see more at https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html.

Comment: Ah right - I hadn't spotted it was so old. Thanks!